# Booting problem in Ubuntu.18.04lts

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub-efi, initramfs, systemd-resolved

Yesterday ,i normally shutdown my laptop. But,when I switch on my laptop ,there was a problem on booting. It is showing that UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY , /dev/sda3 run fsck manually.what will be the reason for the problem happen in my laptop. Please help me?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: First of all thanks for the solution you had given in the previous days , but I rebooted my laptop before asking the question . but  I have a doubt about it that what i should do  if i face the same condition once again.

Comment: Since you haven't run the fsck following my instructions, it sounds like you still have a problem... even though you may be booting right now. Go ahead and do them now, and if you have problems in the future.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's some file system problem with your Ubuntu partition. Fix it this way...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda3`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I done the same procedure which you had meant here. But i got the result as the infinite numbers running completely in the terminal continuously.but i didn't boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode". thanks for the reply bro...

Comment: @ubuntu---noobie You have to do it my way. Please boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and retry.

Comment: @ubuntu---noobie Status please...

Comment: @ubuntu---noobie Status please...